# How do I train test split in Pytorch

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pytorch

What is the best way to encode string values using pytorch?

```
df_train.head():
  country            league        home_team   away_team  home_odds  draw_odds  away_odds  home_score  away_score  dow  month
0  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste     Sport Recife  Imperatriz       1.36       4.31       7.66           2           2    4      2
1  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste              ABC  America RN       2.62       3.30       2.48           2           1    6      2
2  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste  Frei Paulistano     Nautico       5.19       3.58       1.62           0           2    6      2
3  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste      Botafogo PB   Confianca       2.06       3.16       3.50           1           1    6      2
4  Brazil  Copa do Nordeste        Fortaleza       Ceara       2.19       2.98       3.38           1           1    6      2

df_test.shape:
(76544, 11)

df_test.head()
     country          league      home_team      away_team  home_odds  draw_odds  away_odds  home_score  away_score  dow  month
0      World   Club Friendly       Westerlo           Gent       2.93       3.47       2.19         NaN         NaN    4      6
1   Malaysia    Super League       Johor DT       Selangor       1.27       5.59       8.26         NaN         NaN    4      6
2  Argentina  Reserve League        Lanus 2  River Plate 2       2.54       3.12       2.65         NaN         NaN    4      6
3       Asia         AFC Cup    Bali United          Kedah       1.58       4.08       4.93         NaN         NaN    4      6
4   Ethiopia  Premier League  Defence Force     Adama City       2.93       2.16       3.38         NaN         NaN    4      6

df_test.shape:
(599, 11)
```

I perform encoding in sklearn using pandas as:

```
def encode_features(df_train, df_test):
    features = ['country', 'league', 'home_team', 'away_team']
    df_combined = pd.concat([df_train[features], df_test[features]])

    for feature in features:
        le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        le = le.fit(df_combined[feature])
        df_train[feature] = le.transform(df_train[feature])
        df_test[feature] = le.transform(df_test[feature])
    return df_train, df_test


df_train, df_test = encode_features(df_train, df_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

For encoding those four column with strings, you can use label encoder or one hot encoders. Here is the reference class for your case with label encoder.

```
import pandas
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

class MultiColumnLabelEncoder:
    def __init__(self,columns = None):
        self.columns = columns # array of column names to encode

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self # not relevant here

    def transform(self,X):
        output = X.copy()
        if self.columns is not None:
            for col in self.columns:
                output[col] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(output[col])
        else:
            for colname,col in output.iteritems():
                output[colname] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(col)
        return output

    def fit_transform(self,X,y=None):
        return self.fit(X,y).transform(X)

MultiColumnLabelEncoder(columns = ['country', 'league', 'home_team', 'away_team']).fit_transform(df_train)
```

I assume this may help for your case.

Comment: This works. However, I wanted a solution that can work with `pytorch` as it uses tensors and encoding it into `int` is not helpful with `torch`

Comment: You can go with **pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['country', 'league', 'home_team', 'away_team'])**. Probably I don't think there is a specific encoder used for pytorch. Please refer this link [link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/kushal1506/moa-pytorch-feature-engineering-0-01846/notebook). I thought this will help you.